# tcl error "can't find package struct::tree "

Tags: tcl

I tried to use the tree package for TCL but I'm unable to find any documentation at all. When trying to run the examples from http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/struct_tree.html, i get the error

```
can't find package struct::tree
```

Can anyone tell me how to include it in tcl 8.5?

Comment: Have you done "package require struct::tree"?

Comment: Yes I did. I installed tcllib and it's working fine now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `struct::tree` package is part of [Tcllib](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/).

If you are using ActiveTcl, doing a `teacup update` (possibly with elevated permissions, depending on how you installed) will download a copy. I don't know whether all Linuxes have Tcllib done as an appropriate system package, but [Debian does](http://packages.debian.org/sid/tcllib). Otherwise, there's a download link in on the main Tcllib page; Tcllib works just fine as a bunch of `.tcl` files that you include with your application code.

Comment: Im using Ubuntu. Does it mean i can just include the tree.tcl in my other code?